# Hybris: Restricted users able to login to CSCockpit

Tags: authentication, sap-commerce-cloud, cs-cockpit

I'm able to login to cscockpit through user credentials of PCM and CMS cockpits. This is incorrect behavior. I checked the Group access rights of PCM, CMS and CS users in HMC and they look fine to me. Any help what could be the problem?
Many thanks!

PS: I don't have rights to post question on Hybris Wiki and Experts. Also, I could not find any useful info there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cockpit extension defines the 'corePreAuthenticationChecks' bean that take care of authentification, the default configuration for user groups is :

```
<property name="allowedUserGroups">
    <list>
        <value>Admingroup</value>
        <value>Employeegroup</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

Therefore in order to override this behavior, you need to customize the CsCockpit extension (addon or new extension), have a look at 'solrfacetsearch-spring-security.xml' for a example.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the group "cockpitgroup" which is by default added in the productmanager, cmsmanager etc. The cockpitgroup enables the rights to access cockpits which are defined in this group.

"All users and groups which should have access to a cockpit application, should belong to this group".

Also when a user is mapped with more than one group, Hybris does "AND" operation and executes. Hope this would help you.